# libtorch&C++ undefined reference to c10::Error

Tags: c++

Cmake3.17 libtorch 1.2  pytorch1.2  VS2015

```
#include <torch/script.h> // One-stop header.
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <memory>    
int main() {
    torch::jit::script::Module module = torch::jit::load("F:\\test.pt");
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::ones({ 36, 9, 64, 64 }));
    auto outputs = module.forward(inputs).toTuple();    
    std::cout << "ok\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

when i load .pt is correct，but  c10::Error in module.forward(inputs).toTuple();

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please, read our guide on [how to make good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question to add more details and be a little more clear on what is your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `"-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` to your build command. This issue is described in full detail at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13541 which fundamentally indicates that you have an ABI issue.

Comment: I also had similar issue. I tried adding the ```"-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"``` flag during building, but the error still remains.

Comment: These errors arise because of different version of compilers used to compile libraries.

Comment: Thank you. I also realized this later and installed new version of libtorch compatible with my compiler and the error went away!